# Filling dynamic array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

I allocate array of struct in function, but cannot fill those structures with values in same function.

```
#include<sys/sem.h>

void setSemaphores(int N, struct sembuf **wait){

    *wait = malloc(N * sizeof(struct sembuf));

    wait[3]->sem_op = 99; //causes error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int N = 4;
    struct sembuf *wait;

    setSemaphores(N, &wait);

    wait[3].sem_op = 99; //works fine

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't compile (the first error I spotted is the missing type of `N`). Would you please provide a compilable code?

Comment: `(*wait)[3].sem_op = 99;`

Answer (score 2):

In `setSemaphores()`:
`wait` is a pointer to one variable of type `struct sembuf`, not to an array of them.
Thus, `wait[3]` is UB. What you wanted is `(*wait)[3].sem_op`.

Another tip:
Change `*wait = malloc(N * sizeof(struct sembuf));`
to `*wait = malloc(N * sizeof **wait);`.

That easily avoids using the wrong type in a sizeof.